# Solve for two variables, two equations with exponents

Tags: linear-algebra, logarithms, exponential-function

Solve for both k and x, where $5=k(300)^x$ and $80=k(600)^x$

Answer (score 3):

$\dfrac{5}{80}=(\dfrac{300}{600})^x$. Can you proceed from here?

Answer (score 1):

Since $$k=\frac{5}{300^x}=\frac{80}{600^x},$$
we have
$$5\cdot 300^x\cdot 2^x=80\cdot 300^x\Rightarrow 2^x=\frac{80}{5}=16=2^4.$$

Answer (score 0):

Dividing the second equation by the first gives:

$$\frac {80}5 = \left(\frac {600}{300} \right)^x\\
16=2^x\\
x=4$$

Substitute back to get $k$.